# having a user with the same permissions as www-data

Tags: linux, server, permissions

I have a virtual web server running linux and on that I have a user called "user". this is also the user, that i use when i mount the webserver's directory with sshfs. sadly this user cannot write any files for the website i am working on, only the user www-data is allowed to do that. if i use: `chown -R user:user ./` to change the owner, i am allowed to change the data as "user", but now the website cannot be opened in the webbrowser anymore. so i have to change the owner of the files back, after i am done editing the files which is extremely tedious.

I have added the user "user" to the www-data group, but this is not changing anything.

How can I set everything up in a way, that the user "user" can edit the files as well as www-data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the permissions for your files so members of the same group are allowed to write. You can do this with the `chmod g+w -R ./` command, this works for existing files.

However, you will notice that newly created files will be created with the owner set to `user:user`, which would still deny access to `www-data`. You can change this behavior by setting the default ACL like so: `setfacl -R -d -m g:www-data:rw ./`

The setfacl options mean:

- `-R` Recursive
- `-d` Action applies to default ACL
- `-m` Modify the ACL
- `g:www-data:rw` Set group by default to `www-data` and group permission to read and write.

Comment: thank you very much!